# Optional generic type with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have the is generic function type:

```
export type EVCb<T> = (err: any, val?: T) => void;
```

that type can be used like so:

```
const v = function(cb: EVCb<boolean>){
   cb(null, true);  // compiles correctly
};

const v = function(cb: EVCb<boolean>){
   cb(null, 'yo');  // does not compile 
};
```

but I am wondering if there is a way to add an `optional` type for the error parameter, because right now it's always `any`. something like this:

```
export type EVCb<T, E?> = (err: E | any, val?: T) => void;
```

The user would use it like so:

```
EVCb<boolean, Error>
```

or they could choose to omit the second parameter, and just do:

```
EVCb<boolean>
```

is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A type parameter can be optional if you provide a default for it:

```
export type EVCb<T, E = any> = (err: E, val?: T) => void;
```

Comment: This removes errors but the inputted type of the error is not defined automatic based on input type